# Regex remove replace all whitespaces and commas with a plus sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a query like this

```
2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA
```

I need to replace all the white spaces and commas with a plus, so I do this:

```
query = query.replace(/,? /g, '+');
```

Problem is when there are multiple commas or whitespaces it doesn't work (or if there are whitespaces or commas at the end or start of the query. So I need to cover this cases:

```
2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA
2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC,, USA, 
2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA ,
 ,2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA
, 2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA
   2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA
,,2258, Hampton   Street, Columbia, SC, USA
2258, Hampton Street,,,, Columbia, SC, USA 
2258, Hampton Street Columbia, SC, USA,
2258, Hampton Street  ,, Columbia, SC, USA
```

And they all should be:

```
2258+haptom+street+columbia+sc+usa
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Javascript @WaelAbbas

Comment: So, you want to remove them at the end and start, and replace with `+` inside?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works but still got a "+" at the end if there's a whitespace

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
var rx = /^[,\s]+|[,\s]+$|([,\s]+)/g;
s = s.replace(rx, function(_,$1) { return $1 ? '+' : ''; })
```

The pattern matches

- `^[,\s]+` - 1+ commas or whitespace chars at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `[,\s]+$` - 1+ commas or whitespace chars at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `([,\s]+)` - 1+ commas or whitespace chars captured into Group 1

If Group 1 matched the replacement is `+`, else, the replacement is an empty string (removing the whitespaces/commas at the start/end).

See the JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA', '2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC,, USA, ', '2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA ,', ' ,2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA', ', 2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA', '   2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA', ',,2258, Hampton   Street, Columbia, SC, USA', '2258, Hampton Street,,,, Columbia, SC, USA ', '2258, Hampton Street Columbia, SC, USA,', '2258, Hampton Street  ,, Columbia, SC, USA'];
var rx = /^[,\s]+|[,\s]+$|([,\s]+)/g;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s.replace(rx, function(_,$1) {
    return $1 ? '+' : '';
  }))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! God bless smarter people on stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
q.replace(/^[, ]+|[, ]+$/g, '').replace(/[, ]+/g, '+')
```

Example:

```
queries = [
  '2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA',
  '2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC,, USA, ',
  '2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA ,',
  ' ,2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA',
  ', 2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA',
  '   2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA',
  ',,2258, Hampton   Street, Columbia, SC, USA',
  '2258, Hampton Street,,,, Columbia, SC, USA ',
  '2258, Hampton Street Columbia, SC, USA,',
  '2258, Hampton Street  ,, Columbia, SC, USA'
];

queries.forEach(q => {
  console.log(q.replace(/^[, ]+|[, ]+$/g, '').replace(/[, ]+/g, '+'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below two steps example

```js
var inputString = `2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA
2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC,, USA, 
2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA ,
 ,2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA
, 2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA
   2258, Hampton Street, Columbia, SC, USA
,,2258, Hampton   Street, Columbia, SC, USA
2258, Hampton Street,,,, Columbia, SC, USA 
2258, Hampton Street Columbia, SC, USA,
2258, Hampton Street  ,, Columbia, SC, USA`;

var regex = /^[\s*,]+|[\s*,]$|(\s*,*)$|(,*\s*)$|[ ]{2}/gm;

// Clean string first remove space or , in start and end and remove duplicated inside statements
inputString = inputString.replace(regex, ''); 

// Replace any , or space one or more with +
console.log(inputString.replace(/[, ]+/gm, '+'));
```